# Viewing Linked Server Tables on Different Versions of SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We have a SQL Server 2014 with a linked server with SQL Server 2016.

From SSMS on my local machine I can see the remote linked server under Server Objects, but I cannot see any of the tables in the database.

If I login to the machine running SQL Server 2014 and login with the same domain credentials I can see the linked server and the tables.

Suggestions?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM linked_Server.db_name.schema_name.table` If you get error you simply do not have rights to read that table or even see its definition

Comment: Are you sure it's the same credentials and the first instance of SSMS doesn't have another user saved at the connect screen?

Comment: I'm sure.  I'll try the SQL test now.

Comment: @lad2025 I get an error that NT Authority\Anonymous Logon failed.  Weird.... I'm logged in as my domain account.

Comment: @BillGreer So you get the answer. You need to  set correct permission and use correct account.

Comment: Why would I get NT Authority\Anonymous failed.  I'm not logging in using that account?